# Stack overflow when close jquery modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-dialog

I use jquery.validation v 1.6 with jquery 1.5.1 and jquery-ui 1.8.24 when I create jquery **modal** dialog and then try to close it throw exception:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

or

> Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Update you jquery-validate plugin to v. 1.8 or higher.